# Problem with hibernation (s2disk) on 18.04

Tags: hibernate

I have already managed to get s2disk working on my 18.04 machine. I have set up an /swapfile with 8gb Ram and systemd is usind s2disk as suspend-to-hibernate. It works more or less 2-3 times in a row.

Problem is: After 2-3 hibernations (or suspends-to-hibernations) the machine is switching itself off (or better: killing itself due to the fact that the battery is empty; system is not even shuting down but suddenly switched off).

Underlying problem: s2disk is complaining that there is not enough diskspace, so that the hibernation process is cancelled and the laptop is neither in suspend mode nor in hibernation but running till battery dies.

Any ideas how to lets say "clean up" /swapfile so that the space is freed up for s2disk after each hibernation circle?

Comment: (s2disk is from the uswsusp package.)